# Aligning Hexdump Data in a Specific format?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am reading serial data from my Raspberry Pi and all I am doing is a Hexdump
I have to find the header and then go to the 2nd byte of data from header
for ex: ed 13 74, I have to take the value 4 , convert it to decimal and add 2 to it ( in this case its 4+2 = 6, ) and I have to read 6 bytes of data from header

Again I have to move forward find the next packet with header and repeat the same

I am trying to do all this by writing a script

Comment: What have you tried? Switching to a higher-level language could simplify the thing. How are the packages separated?

Comment: Where does the value 4 come from?

Comment: The value 4 is just an example , so for any packet that starts with Ed header , Ed 13 17.. I must fetch the number 7 .. And the crc by default for the packet is 2 so I add 7 and 2 ,,, in this case I should read 9 bytes of data starting from Ed

Comment: I tried pipeline some awk and sed commands with hexdump but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: sudo hexdump -C /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk '{$1=$18=""; print $0}' | awk '$0' RS="\ed" | awk '{print "::ED"$0}' | awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="." In this script I am removing 1 and 18th column which I dont need ! I am searching for ed , and displaying that packet in a new line. I have also added delimiter . for space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description does not tie in well with the hexdump supplied, as all the 2nd bytes after `ed` are `00`.  However, you should try to master at least one of the more sophisticated tools in Unix for string handling, namely `awk`.

You can simplify your data stream by putting exactly one hex number per line. With your example you can pipe it through `tr -s ' ' '\n'`. However, more usefully if you do `man hexdump` you can see it provides options on the output format to print one number per line so that you don't need to further manipulate it. Eg

```
hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"'
```

will provide data like

```
2f
ed
3f
00
08
```

Pipe that data into this script

```
awk '$1=="ed" {
    getline byte1
    getline byte2
    number = strtonum("0x" substr(byte2,2,1))
    print "len is " number
    data = byte1 byte2
    while(number-->0){getline byte; data = data byte}
    print data
} '
```

This checks if the first word on the line is `ed`, then uses `getline` to read the next line into variable byte1, and the line after into byte2. The `substr()` takes the last character, concatenates it with "0x" and calls `strtonum` to convert the hex to decimal. The `while` loop calls getline this number of times and concatenates the data.

Comment: Wow that worked ! A couple of comments,, one : gwak wasn't installed and i did that,,,second, i just modified the line ,,,number = strtonum("0x" substr(byte2,2,1)) +2,, +2 is for CRC,,, and  data = "ed" byte1 byte2 to print ed before that data !! thanks again